# Nodejs : allure-reporter hide step randomly

Tags: node.js, json, debugging, allure

I created a module to generate allure-results, it works. But in the report, allure does no display randomly some tests, however in the allure-results files they are correctly indexed.

[image: the incomplete allure-report]

The T05 which is displayed:

```
{
 "uuid": "23e06df0-377a-11ea-81da-89b3a58be8ac",
 "name": "PIM_SC43_T05_Verification",
 "status": "passed",
 "start": 1579080831567,
 "historyId": "6a0923f083fcc597ada55863ce2382a607635a6bbce0165c459b074bad010e70",
 "stop": 1579080842691,
 "stage": "finished",
 "parameters": [
      {
           "name": "Verification Nom",
           "value": "ROBO_FOURNCIN_FR_1579080384393"
      },
      {
           "name": "Verification Référence",
           "value": "PIMF"
      },
      {
           "name": "Verification Etat",
           "value": "A VALIDER QUALITÉ POMONA"
      }
 ],
 "statusDetails": {
      "known": false,
      "muted": false,
      "flaky": false
 },
 "steps": [],
 "attachments": [],
 "labels": [
      {
           "name": "suite",
           "value": "SC43_ControleValidationFournisseurImpNehParQA"
      },
      {
           "name": "parentSuite",
           "value": "PIM_C08_CreationFournisseurImpNeg_Hygiene"
      }
 ]
}
```

The T05 which is not displayed:

```
{
 "uuid": "bb12f120-377a-11ea-81da-89b3a58be8ac",
 "name": "PIM_SC45_T05_Verification",
 "status": "passed",
 "start": 1579081085234,
 "historyId": "6e9326da31828e5491281a96039aa7e805e534c98a54a8293c4110a45635c61c",
 "stop": 1579081096365,
 "stage": "finished",
 "parameters": [
      {
           "name": "Verification Nom",
           "value": "ROBO_AUTO_HYGIENE_1579080955529"
      },
      {
           "name": "Verification Référence",
           "value": "PIMP"
      },
      {
           "name": "Verification Etat",
           "value": "EN ATTENTE DE VALIDATION FOURNISSEUR"
      }
 ],
 "statusDetails": {
      "known": false,
      "muted": false,
      "flaky": false
 },
 "steps": [],
 "attachments": [],
 "labels": [
      {
           "name": "suite",
           "value": "sc45_FicheProduitHygienePourFournisseurImpNegParFournisseur"
      },
      {
           "name": "parentSuite",
           "value": "PIM_C08_CreationFournisseurImpNeg_Hygiene"
      }
 ]
}
```

The Container of T05 which is not displayed:

```
{
 "uuid": "a4d9dae0-377a-11ea-81da-89b3a58be8ac",
 "name": "sc45_FicheProduitHygienePourFournisseurImpNegParFournisseur",
 "children": [
      "a67a1d60-377a-11ea-81da-89b3a58be8ac",
      "a9755c00-377a-11ea-81da-89b3a58be8ac",
      "ac70c1b0-377a-11ea-81da-89b3a58be8ac",
      "afa056c0-377a-11ea-81da-89b3a58be8ac",
      "b813e1f0-377a-11ea-81da-89b3a58be8ac",
      "bb12f120-377a-11ea-81da-89b3a58be8ac",
      "c4b07d60-377a-11ea-81da-89b3a58be8ac",
      "d73983f0-377a-11ea-81da-89b3a58be8ac",
      "dab8e6b0-377a-11ea-81da-89b3a58be8ac",
      "ef101d90-377a-11ea-81da-89b3a58be8ac",
      "f2923f70-377a-11ea-81da-89b3a58be8ac",
      "2d2a1860-377b-11ea-81da-89b3a58be8ac",
      "30966850-377b-11ea-81da-89b3a58be8ac",
      "59391640-377b-11ea-81da-89b3a58be8ac",
      "5cd61320-377b-11ea-81da-89b3a58be8ac",
      "7dc21d40-377b-11ea-81da-89b3a58be8ac",
      "816338d0-377b-11ea-81da-89b3a58be8ac",
      "89cd9c40-377b-11ea-81da-89b3a58be8ac",
      "93b26ab0-377b-11ea-81da-89b3a58be8ac",
      "96adf770-377b-11ea-81da-89b3a58be8ac"
 ],
 "start": 1579081047950,
 "stop": 1579081461682
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was a little tricky, the allure core concat all steps with the same historyId.